# Swift 3 - custom fade-segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, fade

I am trying to make a custom transition from one ViewController to another, but for some reason i cant seem to get it right.
I want the "fromView" to fade out and the "ToView" to fade ind in, and i didn'
t think that would be so hard - but apparently it is not so easy.

Right now i use a NSObject to declare the transition-function, and call it from "prepare(for segue" in my ViewController. But something is wrong.

My custom-transition:

```
class FadeAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

let duration = 1


func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return TimeInterval(duration)
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from) else {
        return
    }

    guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) else {
    return
    }


    let container = transitionContext.containerView


    container.addSubview(fromView)
    container.addSubview(toView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            fromView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (true) in
            toView.alpha = 1
        })


    }) { (succes) in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(succes)
    } 
}
```

My ViewController.swift:

```
  let fadeAnimater = FadeAnimator()



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destination = segue.destination

    destination.transitioningDelegate = FadeAnimator() as! UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
}
```

Comment: There is already a fade segue animation in iOS called Cross Dissolve.

Comment: Omg.. Thank you! So long time wasted.... Gotta love programming

Comment: Are there a way to set a duration on the Cross Dissolve? :)

Comment: No, it's fixed, sadly.

Comment: When you say "But something is wrong" - what exactly is wrong?